# Searching for a text with several Lines

Tags: powershell

I am struggling right now with an what it seems to be, simple task, I hope you could help me with.

I am reading the BIOS settings from several HP Notebooks and save it into a text file. I want to chek if some certain settings are activated. Even if there is another way to read the Settings I would like to do it this way, because I am really curious how its done.

I think the problem could be the TAB character within the textfile, yet I fail to verify.

The content has the following structure:

```
Virtualization Technology (VTx)
    Disable
    *Enable
Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VTd)
    Disable
    *Enable
```

[Original Textfile BIOS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGWDF.jpg)

For example I want to know whether the "Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VTd)" is enabled or not.

Here is my attempt:

$inputFile = "C:\temp\HP BIOS Utility\BiosConfigurationHP EliteBook 840 G6.txt"

```
<# Method 1: String #>
$filters = 
"Virtualization Technology (VTx)
    Disable
    *Enable"
$Content = Get-Content $inputFile 

if ($Content -contains "$filters") {"Text exists"} {"no"}
```

Some help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Instead of scraping text from the [HP BIOS Configuration Utility (BCU)](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/HP_BCU.html), I recommend you to use [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) using the [HP Client Management Interface](http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/downloads/cmi_whitepaper.pdf) to retrieve the concerned information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PowerShell for Windows:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class hp_biosSetting -filter "Name='Virtualization Technology (VTx)'").CurrentValue
Enable
```

Using PowerShell Core:

```
(Get-CimInstance -Class 'HP_BIOSSetting' -Namespace 'root\HP\InstrumentedBIOS' -filter "Name='Virtualization Technology (VTx)'").CurrentValue
Enable
```

Comment: Thank you Ron it looks great so far, will have a look if it will be an issue with different modell types of HP devices. HP loves to change the name of the settings throuout different BIOS versions.

Comment: I know (I worked for more then 30years for HP), any ways if it is different on other modell types of HP devices, I expect that also to be same case for the configuration utility. The WMI solution is as flexible as what you doing now (e.g. you might use `like` filters on a WMI query level or PowerShell level)  but it is simply more direct. Besides, as with the configuration utility, you are also able change values using WMI.

Answer (score 0):

If you must parse out a file like that, the easiest thing to do IMO is to use `switch -Regex -File` like this:

```
$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\bios.txt' {
    '^(\w.*)'      { $feature = $matches[1] }
    '^\s+\*(\w+)'  { [PsCustomObject]@{Feature = $feature; Enabled = ($matches[1] -like 'Enable*')} }
}

#output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\BiosFeatures.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Using your example this would output:

```
Feature                                          Enabled
-------                                          -------
Virtualization Technology (VTx)                     True
Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VTd)    True
```

Explanation:

The switch runs through the file line-by-line.
The two regexes are

**`'^(\w.*)'`**

```
^           Assert position at the beginning of the string
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \w       Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
   .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *     Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

**`'^\s+\*(\w+)'`**

```
^           Assert position at the beginning of the string
\s          Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\*          Match the character “*” literally
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \w       Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much excatly what I was looking for and it worked! Would not be able to figure it out myself.

Comment: How is it possible to save the content into a text file? Could not figure out at which point to use the out-file commands. Thanks again!